# Not getting the TOKEN after the success of recurring subscription payment

Tags: yii, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

```
Array
(
    [txn_type] => subscr_signup
    [subscr_id] => I-WT2XTR8FF1NX
    [last_name] => testing
    [residence_country] => US
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [item_name] => ilookin's monthly
    [business] => indhumathi.k-facilitator@optisolbusiness.com
    [amount3] => 1.00
    [recurring] => 0
    [address_street] => 1 Main St
    [payer_status] => verified
    [payer_email] => optisol@optisol.com
    [address_status] => confirmed
    [first_name] => optisol
    [receiver_email] => indhumathi.k-facilitator@optisolbusiness.com
    [address_country_code] => US
    [payer_id] => QUMFGMGW2N4Z2
    [address_city] => San Jose
    [reattempt] => 1
    [address_state] => CA
    [subscr_date] => 01:29:58 Apr 19, 2016 PDT
    [address_zip] => 95131
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [address_country] => United States
    [period3] => 1 M
    [mc_amount3] => 1.00
    [address_name] => optisol testing
    [auth] => A0LUGRBFj6LNkWG.xKRjssSW6CnDDxfiPEt6gNkXkpQz7wuKMdiuZAm3B56YywWHBW9Hjc07tetTpy8sD8YAMdQ
    [form_charset] => UTF-8
    [EC-1A5481165X7875926] => 
)
```

Am getting these parameters.But I need token after the success completion of recurring subscription.How to get it after the payment success?

Please Advice

Thanks in Advance.